# finding non zero values in the string using regular expression (regex)

Tags: regex

**String 1:** `_0.05_0.0_0.0_0.0_0.0_0.0_`

**String 2:**  `_8.5_5.0_0.0_0.0_0.0_1.25_`

These are order quantity separated by underscore. How can i count non zero order count using regular expression.
Non zero order count in string 1 is 1 (`0.05`) and in string 2 is 3 (`8.5`,`5.0`,`1.25`).

**Tried so far**:  `^_0.0_$`, but it giving wrong result.

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?<=_)(?![0.]+_)\d+\.\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9LjefP/1/).

*Details*

- `(?<=_)` - a `_` must occur immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?![0.]+_)` - immediately to the right, there cannot be only zeros and `.`
- `\d+\.\d+` - one or more digits, `.`, one or more digits.

You can also use

```php
(?<!\d)(?!0+\.0+(?!\d))\d+\.\d+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9LjefP/2). *Details*:

- `(?<!\d)` - a left-hand digit boundary
- `(?!0+\.0+(?!\d))` - no one or more zeros, `.`, one or more zeros not followed with a digit are allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `\d+\.\d+` - one or more digits, `.`, one or more digits.